# Replace values in columns of dataframe based on dictionary not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, replace

You can read the exact problem below, but this is essentially what I'm trying to do:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                        'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                        'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                        'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']})

newVals = dict({'A0': 0,
             'A1': 1,
              'A2': 2,
             'A3': 3})
for key, value in newVals.items():
    df1['A'].replace({key, value})
```

And when I do this, the resulting data frame has no change.

Initial Post:

Ok so the data I am analyzing accidents in the workplace from OSHA (osha_accident_injury.csv). Each row is a particular person who was injured in an accident. Each column is a characteristic of the person or the accident itself. And each characteristic is encoded as an integer that has a corresponding string value. I want to replace each integer with its string definition. The mappings of numbers to strings are listed in osha_accident_lookup.csv. The mappings of accident codes can be found in osha_accident_dictionary.csv, but I manually input them into a map.

However, some of the integers map to multiple strings, so it also depends on the accident_code from osha_accident_lookup.csv. Because of this, I create a list that holds a dictionary (maps integer to string value) for each particular accident code. However, when I try to replace each column with its particular dictionary, it returns the original dataframe instead of the one with string values. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
# create list of all distinct accident codes
code_list = []
for index in osha_accident_lookup.index:
    if osha_accident_lookup['accident_code'][index] not in code_list:
        code_list.append(osha_accident_lookup['accident_code'][index])

# remove values not found in actual data
code_list.remove('PTYP')
code_list.remove('COST')
code_list.remove('ENDU')

# create list of dictionaries, s.t. each item maps accident number to accident value
# there is a unique map for each unique accident code
mapList = []
for code in code_list:
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(osha_accident_lookup[osha_accident_lookup['accident_code'] == code])
    temp_map = dict(zip(temp_df['accident_number'], temp_df['accident_value']))
    mapList.append(temp_map)

# create dictionary that maps code from osha_accident_lookup to column name in osha_accident_injury.csv
code_to_column = dict({"OCC": "occ_code", 'CAUS': 'fat_cause', 'DEGR': 'degree_of_inj',
                          "OPER": "const_op_cause", "EN": 'evn_factor', "FT": 'event_type', "HU": 'hum_factor', "IN":
                           "nature_of_inj", "BD": "part_of_body", "SO": "src_of_injury", "TASK": 'task_assigned'})

# replace numbers in injury data with string values of what the #'s represent
iterator = 0
for item in mapList:
    code = code_list[iterator]
    col_name = code_to_column[code]
    for key, value in item.items():
        osha_accident_injury[col_name].replace({key: value})
    iterator += 1
```

osha_accident_injury.csv (first 10 rows):

| FIELD1 | summary_nr | rel_insp_nr | age | sex | nature_of_inj | part_of_body | src_of_injury | event_type | evn_factor | hum_factor | occ_code | degree_of_inj | task_assigned | hazsub | const_op | const_op_cause | fat_cause | fall_distance | fall_ht | injury_line_nr | load_dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 18 | 10006732 | 0 |  | 10.0 | 12.0 | 15.0 | 13.0 | 18.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 |  | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 |  |  | 1 | 2017-03-20 01:00:11 EDT |
| 1 | 26 | 159996 | 0 |  | 21.0 | 19.0 | 42.0 | 5.0 | 13.0 | 9.0 | 0.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 |  | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 |  |  | 1 | 2017-03-20 01:00:11 EDT |
| 2 | 34 | 10013225 | 0 |  | 21.0 | 4.0 | 19.0 | 8.0 | 18.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 0270 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 |  |  | 1 | 2017-03-20 01:00:11 EDT |
| 3 | 42 | 10014439 | 0 |  | 1.0 | 10.0 | 24.0 | 2.0 | 3.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 | 2.0 | 2.0 |  | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 |  |  | 1 | 2017-03-20 01:00:11 EDT |
| 4 | 59 | 19523588 | 0 |  | 5.0 | 4.0 | 16.0 | 10.0 | 9.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 | 2.0 | 1.0 |  | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 |  |  | 1 | 2017-03-20 01:00:11 EDT |
| 5 | 59 | 19523588 | 0 |  | 21.0 | 5.0 | 16.0 | 8.0 | 9.0 | 14.0 | 0.0 | 2.0 | 2.0 |  | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 |  |  | 2 | 2017-03-20 01:00:11 EDT |
| 6 | 59 | 19523588 | 0 |  | 21.0 | 5.0 | 16.0 | 6.0 | 9.0 | 14.0 | 0.0 | 2.0 | 2.0 |  | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 |  |  | 3 | 2017-03-20 01:00:11 EDT |
| 7 | 59 | 19523588 | 0 |  | 21.0 | 5.0 | 16.0 | 8.0 | 9.0 | 14.0 | 0.0 | 2.0 | 2.0 |  | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 |  |  | 4 | 2017-03-20 01:00:11 EDT |
| 8 | 59 | 19523588 | 0 |  | 21.0 | 5.0 | 16.0 | 8.0 | 9.0 | 14.0 | 0.0 | 2.0 | 2.0 |  | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 |  |  | 5 | 2017-03-20 01:00:11 EDT |
| 9 | 59 | 19523588 | 0 |  | 21.0 | 5.0 | 16.0 | 8.0 | 9.0 | 14.0 | 0.0 | 2.0 | 2.0 |  | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 |  |  | 6 | 2017-03-20 01:00:11 EDT |

osha_accident_lookup.csv (first 10 rows):

| accident_code | accident_number | accident_value | accident_letter | load_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OPER | 1 | Backfilling and compacting |  | 2018-11-09 20:56:02 EST |
| OPER | 2 | Bituminous concrete placement |  | 2018-11-09 20:56:02 EST |
| OPER | 3 | Construction of playing fields, tennis courts |  | 2018-11-09 20:56:02 EST |
| SO | 1 | AIRCRAFT |  | 2018-11-09 20:56:02 EST |
| SO | 2 | AIR PRESSURE |  | 2018-11-09 20:56:02 EST |
| SO | 3 | ANIMAL/INS/REPT/ETC. |  | 2018-11-09 20:56:02 EST |
| OCC | 757 | Separating, filtering & clarifying mach. operators |  | 2018-11-09 20:56:02 EST |
| OCC | 758 | Compressing and compacting machine operators |  | 2018-11-09 20:56:02 EST |
| OCC | 759 | Painting and paint spraying machine operators |  | 2018-11-09 20:56:02 EST |
| OCC | 763 | Roasting and baking machine operators, food |  | 2018-11-09 20:56:02 EST |

osha_data_dictionary.csv (first 10 rows):

| table_name | column_name | attribute_name | definition | column_datatype | display_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| osha_accident | nonbuild_ht | Non Building Height | Construction - height in feet when not a building | Numeric, Length=4 | Height for Non-Building |
| osha_accident | project_type | Project Type | Construction - project type (code table PTYP) | Alphanumeric, Length:1 | Project Type |
| osha_accident | event_date | Event Date | Date of accident (yyyymmdd) | Numeric, Length=8 | Event Date |
| osha_accident | event_keyword | Event Keyword | Contains comma separated keywords entered by ERG during the review process. | Alphanumeric, Length:200 | Event Keyword |
| osha_accident | report_id | Report ID | Identifies the OSHA federal or state reporting jurisdiction | Numeric, Length=7 | Reporting ID |
| osha_accident | event_desc | Event Description | Short description of event | Alphanumeric, Length:60 | Event Description |
| osha_accident | load_dt | Load Date Timestamp | The date the load was completed. | date | No Label |
| osha_accident | summary_nr | Summary NR | Identifies the accident OSHA-170 form | Numeric, Length=9 | Summary NR |
| osha_accident | fatality | Fatality | X=Fatality is associated with accident | Alphanumeric, Length:1 | Fatality |

Comment: Try using `merge`. Also, you can also provide more information by telling us which columns from which csv suppose to map to which columns in another csv

Comment: I just gave an abstracted version of my question that has the same problem. Does this make the question any easier to answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method based on your example.

```
df1['A'] = df1['A'].map(newVals)
```